# How to add a alert panel in all the Grafana Dashboard

Tags: grafana, influxdb, telegraf-inputs-plugin, grafana-alerts

We are using grafana to visualize the influx data. There are multiple dashboard created in. Because of some technical issue there may not be new data in Influx to display in the dashboard because of some downtime.

Is there a possibilities that I can add a panel in all the dashboard with an alert message of the downtime. So that dash board users don't have to go anywhere and notified about the downtime there itself.

Thanks

Comment: U should check this [function](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v0.13/query_language/functions/#elapsed), it could help you.

Comment: Thanks Jean for reply, I am looking for a alert message to be displayed in all the dashboard. would be something like a pop up message in all the pages in website

Comment: What do you mean by "all the pages in website"? You want to create a pop up wich is displayed  in grafana, even if you don't are on the specified dashboard ?

Comment: yes. correct .. irrespective of the dashboard

Answer (score 0):

I think that it's not possible to configure a pop up like you want with grafana.
Find another notification [channel](https://grafana.com/docs/alerting/notifications/) (e-mail,discord,slack,...). 
If you really want a pop up, this wont be configured in Grafana but in Javascript. To do that, you'll have to custom your Grafana page.For that, i can't help ou.